# Почему IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android

Я работаю с Camera2API и в части кода где мне нужно взять картинку для сохранения на 3-м кадре вылетает приложение с такой ошибкой

> CameraBackground
>   Process: com.example.android.camera2basic, PID: 7167
>                                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: maxImages (2) has already been acquired, call #close before acquiring more.
>                                                                                       at android.media.ImageReader.acquireNextImage(ImageReader.java:352)
>                                                                                       at com.example.android.camera2basic.CameraActivity$3.onImageAvailable(CameraActivity.java:368)

Я так понимаю, что я что то не закрываю? Он просит вызвать `close` перед тес как продолжать, но я не пойму где и что нужно закрывать?

и вот строчка в которой вылетает код

```
@Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

       --> saveInMetadata(reader.acquireNextImage(), imageDescription);
    }

};
```

вылетает когда я делаю эту часть `reader.acquireNextImage()`

Comment: Вам же в ошибке написано, что картинок максимум две. Видимо да, надо что-то закрыть перед запросом 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как минимум нужно закрывать полученный объект `Image`:

```
@Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
       Image image = null;
       try {
            image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
            saveInMetadata(image, imageDescription);
       } finally {
           if(image != null) image.close(); 
       }
    }
};
```